# Adjust the exponent to switch between notations using siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I have a big question about the `siunitx` package and I hope somebody out there can help me.

At first I want to use the automatic number conversion of the package. So I defined:

```
\sisetup{scientific-notation = engineering}
```

But now every number is converted into the engineering format. For example: `0.01` => `10x10^3` But I want that this number is not converted automatically.

Is there an option to adjust, which tells the package at which max. Exponent number this conversion to `scientific-notation` should take place?

I have really a lot numbers in a paper and it would be really hard to put the scientific-notation on or off for each number manually.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 11):

I do not see anything in the documentation to control this behavior.

For the case where there are a few exceptions, you can manually switch it off for the ones you want with the `\num[scientific-notation=false]{}`.

Alternatively, if you can define exactly when you want the  exponent to be added you can redefine the behavior of `\num` based on its value.  Below I have defined `\num` to apply `scientific-notation=false` if

```
-\Threshold <= number <= \Threshold
```

where `\Threshold` is a value you define.  With `\Threshold=0.09` you get the results in the **New** column below for the value given in the **Num** column:

[image]

### Notes:

- In the question it is suggested to use a maximum exponent to determine if scientific notation is to be used. I am not sure that such a solution is viable in general.  Perhaps a solution based on the number of digits might work.  Once a better algorithm is determined, the macro `\IfLessThanOrEqual` can be adjusted to suit.

### Code:

Below I have adapted [this solution from how to test if a number is negative](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15303/4301) to define `\IfLessThanOrEqual`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\sisetup{scientific-notation = engineering}
\newcommand*{\Threshold}{0.09}%

\newcommand\IfLessThanOrEqual[4]{%
    \begingroup%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\var}{abs(#1)-#2}%
        \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\var<=0,1,0)}%
        \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt= 1 pt%
                #3%
            \else%
                #4%
        \fi%
    \endgroup%
}%

\let\OldNum\num%
\renewcommand*{\num}[2][]{%
    \IfLessThanOrEqual{#2}{\Threshold}{%
        \OldNum[scientific-notation=false,#1]{#2}%
    }{%
        \OldNum[#1]{#2}%
    }%
}%


\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Row}[1]{#1 & \OldNum{#1} & \num{#1}}%

\begin{tabular}{l l l}
Num & Old & New\\
\Row{0.01}\\
\Row{0.09}\\
\Row{0.091}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The related question [Scientific Notation Only For Large Numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111670/scientific-notation-only-for-large-numbers) just got a perfect answer from Bruno le Floch, I supposed it would help to display it here as well.

The answer uses the package `expl3` and defines a new command to test whether the number to be printed surpasses the threshold: `\fpcmpTF`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation=true}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new_eq:NN \fpcmpTF \fp_compare:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\ThresholdLow}{0.01} % Change to your taste
\newcommand*{\ThresholdHigh}{100}

\let\OldNum\num%
\renewcommand*{\num}[2][]{%
    \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)<=\ThresholdLow}{%
        \OldNum[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}%
    }{%
        \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)>=\ThresholdHigh}{%
            \OldNum[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}%
        }{%
            \OldNum[scientific-notation=false,#1]{#2}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Row}[1]{#1 & \OldNum{#1} & \num{#1}}%
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
Num & Old & New\\
\Row{0.01}\\
\Row{0.1}\\
\Row{1}\\
\Row{10}\\
\Row{100}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like this, then be sure to pass the vote to Bruno's answer at [How to subtract both very large numbers and numbers smaller than one?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/how-to-subtract-both-very-large-numbers-and-numbers-smaller-than-one/113174?noredirect=1#113174).