# Make threshold compatible with comma as decimal separator

Tags: siunitx, expl3

I am using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113145/21557) code to get a better control when scientific notation should be used and when not.

The problem is, that it doesn't seem not to be compatible when using comma as decimal separator, for example:

```
% 
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[locale=DE,per-mode=fraction,round-pad=false]{siunitx}

\usepackage[low=1e-2,high=1e3]{threshold}

\begin{document}

\SI{5.2}{m} works but %\SI{5,2}{m} not. 
\end{document}
```

```
% threshold.sty
\RequirePackage{expl3,kvoptions,siunitx}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=threshold,prefix=threshold@}
\DeclareStringOption[1]{low}[0.001]
\DeclareStringOption[1]{high}[100]
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\sisetup{scientific-notation=true}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new_eq:NN \fpcmpTF \fp_compare:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\let\OldNum\num%
\renewcommand*{\num}[2][]{%
    \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)<=\threshold@low}{%
        \OldNum[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}%
    }{%
        \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)>=\threshold@high}{%
            \OldNum[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}%
        }{%
            \OldNum[scientific-notation=false,#1]{#2}%
        }%
    }%
}

\let\OldSI\SI%
\renewcommand*{\SI}[3][]{%
    \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)<=\threshold@low}{%
        \OldSI[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}{#3}%
    }{%
        \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)>=\threshold@high}{%
            \OldSI[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}{#3}%
        }{%
            \OldSI[scientific-notation=false,#1]{#2}{#3}%
        }%
    }%
}
```

How can I make it work with comma separator as well.

Comment: In `fp`, if  `abs(#2)` is fed a number with commas instead of decimal points, it will probably fail.  You probably need something like `abs(\num[output-decinal-marker=., ]{#2})` or something in that line... (no time to check now)

Comment: @Rmano doubt that this will work, `\num` isn't expandable, will not work in `abs()` :) What could work would be: `\RequirePackage{etl}`, then after your `\ExplSyntaxOn` put `\etl_new_replace_once:Nn \thresholdcomma { , }`, then in `abs(#2)` use `abs(\thresholdcomma{#2}{.})` instead.

Comment: Yes --- right you are. And @Julia: I suggest NOT to overload `\num` --- nor any basic command. Use your own macro...

Comment: @Rmano especially since the way `\num` and `\SI` are copied here only works because `siunitx` uses `\NewDocumentCommand` and not `\newcommand`.

Comment: @Julia you should use `\NewCommandCopy` instead of `\let` for this.

Comment: @Skillmon: Thanks it works! Maybe you can convert the comment to an answer such that I can accept it. I further noticed that `\SI{e-2}{m}` (instead of `\SI{1e-2}{m}`) raises a similar error. Do you have also an idea about that? (I cannot just replace `e` by `1e` since then `1e` would be replaced by `11e`, so one have to use a regexp match or something like that).

Comment: I've added a suggestion to the original question that builds a threshold mode into `siunitx` directly

Answer (score 4):

### Disclaimer

I don't generally advice to copy and redefine the commands `\SI` and `\num`, hence this answer should be taken more as a "this is the way this could be done, even though it shouldn't". `siunitx` has interfaces to create new commands (or alter the existing ones) which could be used to implement the desired effects of this question. To [quote the package author:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655525/make-threshold-compatible-with-comma-as-decimal-separator/655602?noredirect=1#comment1633728_655602)

> one shouldn't copy `\num` or `\SI` *at all* - there is a documented programmers API for `siunitx` and one should use that to implement modified document commands.

---

Though I suggest proper input (especially for your `e-2` interpreted as `1e-2`), the following implements both. I also dropped `kvoptions` for the key=value interface built into LaTeX since recent versions (falling back to the compatible `l3keys2e`), and restructured your sty-file a bit.

### Package

```
% threshold.sty
\RequirePackage{expl3,siunitx,etl}
\ProvidesExplPackage{threshold}{2022-08-30}{v0}{custom package mangling siunitx}

\etl_new_replace_once:Nn \julia_threshold_replace_comma:nn { , }
\cs_new:Npn \julia_threshold_parse_number:n #1
  {
    \exp_args:Ne \julia_threshold_mayhaps_add_one:n
      { \julia_threshold_replace_comma:nn {#1} { . } }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \julia_threshold_mayhaps_add_one:n #1
  { \tl_if_head_eq_charcode:nNT {#1} e {1} #1 }


\fp_new:N \l_julia_threshold_low_fp
\fp_new:N \l_julia_threshold_high_fp

\keys_define:nn { julia/threshold }
  {
     low  .code:n =
      \fp_set:Nn \l_julia_threshold_low_fp
        { \julia_threshold_parse_number:n {#1} }
    ,low  .initial:n = 0.001
    ,high  .code:n =
      \fp_set:Nn \l_julia_threshold_high_fp
        { \julia_threshold_parse_number:n {#1} }
    ,high .initial:n = 100
  }

\cs_if_exist:NTF \ProcessKeyOptions
  { \ProcessKeyOptions[julia/threshold] }
  {
    \RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
    \ProcessKeysOptions{julia/threshold}
  }

\NewCommandCopy\OldNum\num
\NewCommandCopy\OldSI\SI
\sisetup{scientific-notation=true}

\RenewDocumentCommand \num { O{} m }
  {
    \fp_compare:nTF
      {
        abs ( \julia_threshold_parse_number:n {#2} )
        <=
        \l_julia_threshold_low_fp
      }
      {
        \OldNum[scientific-notation=true, #1]
          { \julia_threshold_mayhaps_add_one:n {#2} }
      }
      {
        \fp_compare:nTF
          {
            abs ( \julia_threshold_parse_number:n {#2} )
            >=
            \l_julia_threshold_high_fp
          }
          {
            \OldNum[scientific-notation=true, #1]
              { \julia_threshold_mayhaps_add_one:n {#2} }
          }
          {
            \OldNum[scientific-notation=false, #1]
              { \julia_threshold_mayhaps_add_one:n {#2} }
          }
      }
  }

\RenewDocumentCommand \SI { O{} m m }
  {
    \fp_compare:nTF
      {
        abs ( \julia_threshold_parse_number:n {#2} )
        <=
        \l_julia_threshold_low_fp
      }
      {
        \OldSI[scientific-notation=true, #1]
          { \julia_threshold_mayhaps_add_one:n {#2} } {#3}
      }
      {
        \fp_compare:nTF
          {
            abs ( \julia_threshold_parse_number:n {#2} )
            >=
            \l_julia_threshold_high_fp
          }
          {
            \OldSI[scientific-notation=true, #1]
              { \julia_threshold_mayhaps_add_one:n {#2} } {#3}
          }
          {
            \OldSI[scientific-notation=false, #1]
              { \julia_threshold_mayhaps_add_one:n {#2} } {#3}
          }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \thresholdsetup { m }
  { \set_keys:nn { julia/threshold } {#1} }
```

### Document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[locale=DE,per-mode=fraction,round-pad=false]{siunitx}

\usepackage[low=1e-2,high=1e3]{threshold}

\begin{document}
\SI{5.2}{m} works but \SI{5,2}{m} and \SI{e-2}{m} not.
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: I know you know this, but really one shouldn't copy `\num` or `\SI` _at all_ - there is a documented programmers API for `siunitx` and one should use that to implement modified document commands.

Comment: @Skillmon: Thanks a lot again. Just as I wanted to accept the answer I have seen Joseph Wright's comment and that he added another solution to the original question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655615/4011) which also seems to be compatible with comma and e. So I am not sure, if it's a good idea to accept your answer.

Comment: @Julia I'm not on a hunt for ticks (as long as egreg doesn't get the tick instead of me :P), just "accept" the answer you think answers your question best, or none if your requirements aren't fulfilled by any, or none if you intend to wait for another better answer, or tick and then later tick another answer if one pops up.