# How to subtract both very large numbers and numbers smaller than one?

Tags: errors, calculations

In the context of [Scientific Notation Only For Large Numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111670/scientific-notation-only-for-large-numbers/113145#113145) have we been looking for a way to handle large numbers, as `pgfmathparse` can't cope with these. The only package we could find was `bigintcalc`, with the problem that it only works with integers.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigintcalc}
\begin{document}
\bigintcalcSub{1}{100}
\end{document}
```

works fine, but

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigintcalc}
\begin{document}
\bigintcalcSub{0.1}{100}
\end{document}
```

gives an error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   .
l.4 \bigintcalcSub{0.1}{100}
```

So apparently `\bigintcalcSub` (or `bigintcalc` at all) is not the way to go. How can one handle large numbers that are not integers?

**Edit:** of course one can use an if statement to check if a number is big, and then only use it in that case, but that would be a bit hacky, wouldn't it?

**Edit 2:** to be more precise, we're trying to make a command that tests whether any number is greater than a certain threshold (and then do something if it is). There are both numbers as 0.01 and numbers as 1e75 fed to this command. `pgfmathparse` can do the first, `bigintcalc` can do the second, but is there something that can do both, so that the workarounds with if statements can be avoided and also large numbers that are *not* integers can be processed?

Comment: The package is for dealing with integers (the clue is in the name): you want to deal with floating point or fixed point numbers. Could you explain the context better, and we can point to the best solution.

Comment: @JosephWright You're right, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `l3fp` package can compute expressions involving floating points, with 16 significant digits, with a large range of exponents (currently positive numbers range in [10^-10000, 10^10000], but this may change a bit).  If 16 digits is enough for your purposes, you could use that.  Some day, I'll code an arbitrary precision floating point unit, but that takes time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
  \cs_new_eq:NN \fpcmpTF \fp_compare:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  $0.1-100$ is $\fpeval{0.1-100}$, and it is
  \fpcmpTF{0.1-100 < -99}{greater}{smaller} than $-99$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sadly, we need to display numbers such as 1e75, as described in the question. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Betohaku I don't see the issue: `l3fp` can manipulate numbers from 1e-10000 to 1e10000 (and negative numbers too).  The question is whether your numbers have more than 16 significant figures, e.g., 1.23456789123456789e75 would be rounded to 1.234567891234568e75, which may be a problem in some applications.

Comment: In that case I misread the ambiguous range [-10000,10000] as being a range between these numbers instead of exponents of these numbers. I apologize.

Comment: I have now taken a good look at http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf, but I couldn't find how to apply it to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111670/scientific-notation-only-for-large-numbers/ (where the problem arose). Apparently LaTeX doesn't like `$` in if statements and `pgfmathparse`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Betohaku I don't know what you tried: in particular, I don't understand where you tried putting `$`.  Does it have a special meaning in pgfmath?  Replacing `\IfLessThanOrEqual{#2}{\ThresholdLow}{...}{...}` by `\fpcmpTF{abs(#2)<=\ThresholdLow}{...}{...}` in [your self-answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113145/2707) (with `\fpcmpTF` defined as `\fp_compare:nTF`) should work (of course, `\IfGreaterThanOrEqual` should be changed in the same way).

Comment: This is perfect! I will add your suggestion to the answer. FYI: it wasn't a self-answer (questioner != me) :P.

Answer (score 4):

run with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$0.1-100$ is $\directlua{tex.print(0.1-100)}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The package `xintfrac` may be used for such computations. The package is primarily concerned with computations, not typesetting, so I have added here a little macro to transmit the typesetting task to other packages such as `siunitx` or `numprint`.

Update: I wondered in the comments to the code below if wrapping across lines was possible with siunitx, or with numprint in mathmode. From very brief examination of some log a test document using `\showoutput` it seems that

1. `siunitx` puts the whole thing in a `\hbox`, whether in math mode or in text, and additionally also encloses the thousand separator in a `\hbox`,
2. `numprint`, when in math mode, typesets the thousand separator in a `\hbox`, but when in text mode, it does not: hence with `numprint`+`text mode` wrapping is possible (the entire thing is fortunately `not` enclosed in a `\hbox`), but in math mode it does not seem to be.

I apologize for these details perhaps only indirectly related to the OP's question: but if we are to subtract power of tens like `10^{100}-1`, we have to think about how to print the resulting one hundred nine's.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color} % for testing an option of siunitx

% formatting numbers with macro \np of numprint
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/numprint
\usepackage[np]{numprint}
\npthousandsep{\allowbreak\,} 
% The \allowbreak allows very long numbers to wrap at endlines
% (but does not work in math mode, I didn't investigate why, perhaps numprint
% uses an \hbox) 
\npdecimalsign{.}

% formatting with macro \num of siunitx
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/siunitx
% I don't know if very long numbers
% wrapping at endlines are possible with it. I tried the following option but it
% doesn't do what I hoped for:
\usepackage[group-separator={\allowbreak\,}]{siunitx}

% computes expandably with long fractions and decimal numbers
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/xint
\usepackage{xintfrac} 

% The next macro prepares a decimal fraction as output by macros of the xintfrac
% package for printing by specialized software.

% Another macro could be written to directly prepare the number in scientific
% notation, but here we simply prepare the number in a.b form with b the
% possibly empty strings of digits after the decimal mark (which is a dot), and
% the transformation into scientific notation can be done at the level of the 
% typesetting package. 

% The first parameter to \decprint is optional and is the command to be applied.
% The default is \np from the numprint package. But one may use for example
% [{\num[key=value]}] to employ \num from the siunitx package with some options.

% The second argument is mandatory and is the decimal number to be typeset. On
% input, xintfrac understands the following format: a, or a.b, or a[c], or
% a.b[c], where [c] means 10 to the power c, and a and b are strings of digits.

% Example: \decprint {\xintAdd {1[-10]}{1[10]}}, which first computes the sum of
% 1e-10 and 1e10 (xintfrac does not understand the scientific notation, it uses 
% brackets rather than e or E) and then
% prints the result using \np command from numprint package.

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\decprint}[2][\np]
   {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\dec@print\xintREZ{#2}{#1}}

\def\dec@print #1/#2[#3]#4{%
    \ifnum #3<0
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {#4{\xintTrunc {-#3}{#1[#3]}}}% non-zero digits after decimal point
    {#4{\xintDSH {-#3}{#1}}}% number is an integer, no decimal point needed
    \ifcase\XINT@isOne{#2} 
       \expandafter\@firstofone % unexpected, denominator wasn't power of ten
    \or\expandafter\@gobble
    \fi {/#4{#2}}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

  $0.1-100$ is $\decprint{\xintSub{0.1}{100}}$, and it is
  \ifcase\xintCmp{\xintSub{0.1}{100}}{-99}
  equal \or greater \else smaller \fi than $-99$.

  $0.01-10^{10}$ is \decprint{\xintSub{0.01}{1[10]}}.

  $0.01-10^{10}$ is \decprint[\num]{\xintSub{0.01}{1[10]}}.

  $0.01-10^{75}$ is \decprint{\xintSub{0.01}{1[75]}}.

  $0.01-10^{75}$ is \decprint[{\num[mode=text]}]{\xintSub{0.01}{1[75]}}.

  $3.14-\np{5e-15}+\np{3e15}$ is \decprint{\xintSumExpr
    {3.14}{-5[-15]}{3[15]}\relax }

  $3.14-\np{5e-15}+\np{3e15}$ is \decprint[{\num[mode=text]}]{\xintSumExpr
    {3.14}{-5[-15]}{3[15]}\relax }

  $3.14-\np{5e-25}+\np{3e25}$ is \decprint{\xintSumExpr
    {3.14}{-5[-25]}{3[25]}\relax } and we could make it wrap accross lines using
  \textbackslash np.

  $3.14-\np{5e-25}+\np{3e25}$ is \decprint[{\num[color=blue]}]{\xintSumExpr
    {3.14}{-5[-25]}{3[25]}\relax } and we tried but failed to let it wrap
  accross lines using \textbackslash num.


\end{document}
```

[image]