# Coloring negative and positive numbers automatically

Tags: tables, color, pgfplotstable

I believe `numprint.sty` is not working.  at least the manual states that *Printing negative numbers in red does not work. Only the minus sign is printed in red. When was this bug introduced?*  Some earlier `sx` solutions that are based on a gobble of the minus sign don't propagate through macros.  however, an adaptation of `tikz` (as explained in [How to test if a number is negative](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15297/how-to-test-if-a-number-is-negative)) works.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newbox\boxcca

\newcommand\ifPositif[3]{ 
  \begingroup
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\var}{#1}
  \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\var>=0,1,0)} 
  \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt= 1 pt 
  \color{blue}{#2}
  \else 
  \color{red}{#3}
  \fi 
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\cnum}[1]{\ifPositif{#1}{#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\cnum{1.0}  %% works
\cnum{-3}  %% works

\newcommand{\useinmacro}[1]{\cnum{#1}}  %% works

\useinmacro{22}  %% works
\useinmacro{-23}  %% works

\begin{lrbox}{\boxcca} -123.2 \end{lrbox}  %% works

\end{document}
```

unfortunately, I could not get this to work in my tabulars with

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\boxcca}} r <{\end{lrbox}\cnum{\boxcca}}}

\begin{tabular}{R R}
  -1 & 2 \\
  3 & -4 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I tried many variations, and I would guess my error is obvious to the eye of the expert and easy to fix.  advice (as always) appreciated.

regards,

PS:  til tantau seems like a genius to me.  how in the world did he manage to code tikz into tex??  a moment ago, I also discovered christian feuersaenger's pgfplotstable and marco's answer in [Automatic coloring of numbers according to size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57334/automatic-coloring-of-numbers-according-to-size) .  this may be adaptable, too.  except for its long names, pgfplotstable looks insanely great---it has the ability to make whitespace or '|' the tabular separator!  wow.  I presume pgfplotstable means giving up booktabs, array, and a couple of other tabular enhancements that I have become fond of, but it seems worth it.  of course, if I do this, the above question is probably obsolete.

Comment: your cnum macro tests tokens but you pass it a box the content of which is opaque to the macro layer of tex. You could use the catchcell package to grab the table cells as a macro

Comment: Er... so what is the status of this question? What, for that matter, is the question?

Comment: question is : how do I define a newcolumntype that colors negative values in red and positive numbers in blue.  will look at catchcell and post it if I can figure it out.  thx, david.

Answer (score 13):

It is easy with the `collcell` package.

Simply define

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\cnum}r<{\endcollectcell}}
```

Note also that `\cnum` can be simply defined as

```
\newcommand\cnum[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\var}{#1}%
  \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\var>=0,1,0)}%
  \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt= 1 pt%
  \textcolor{blue}{#1}%
  \else%
  \textcolor{red}{#1}%
  \fi%
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand\cnum[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\var}{#1}%
  \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\var>=0,1,0)}%
  \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt= 1 pt%
  \textcolor{blue}{#1}%
  \else%
  \textcolor{red}{#1}%
  \fi%
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\cnum}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{RR}
  1.0 & 2 \\
  3 & -4 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If the numbers are meant to be typeset in math mode, define the column as

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$\collectcell\cnum}r<{\endcollectcell$}}
```

and the result will be

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `-4` (or at least the minus symbol) be in math mode?

Comment: @Mico I don't know. It isn't in math mode in the OP's example.

Comment: the solutions are an embarrassment of riches.  thank you, karl (and others).  I need to do some experimenting on relative typesetting efficiency [esp on pgfplotstable] next to decide which one I should use on long docs...

Answer (score 10):

This is possible with `siunitx` too. It provides the option `negative-color = <color>` which can be used with `S` column type. Advantage of `siunitx` include many formatting options for numbers in the document.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\sisetup{negative-color = red}
\newcolumntype{R}{S[color=blue,negative-color = red]}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{RR}
  1.0 & 2 \\
  3 & -4 \\
\end{tabular}

\num{-15673}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As suggested by Mico, you can define

```
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{S[color=blue,table-format=#1]}
```

so that alignment options can be used with `R` column:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\sisetup{negative-color = red}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{S[color=blue,table-format=#1]}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{R{1.1}R{-1.0}}
  1.0 & 2 \\
  3 & -4 \\
\end{tabular}

\num{-15673}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Given that `negative-color = red` is set as a global option, is it necessary to repeat it in the definition of the `R` column type? One could make the definition of `R` a bit more flexible, say, as `\newcolumntype{R}[1]{S[color=blue,table-format=#1]}`. This would make it possible to state the two column formats as `R[1.1]` and `R[-1.0]`, respectively, and enable nice, i.e., tight spacing of the columns.

Comment: @Mico Not necessary to repeat it in `R` column type. I defined it globally just for using `\num`. The second suggestion is good. I will modify accordingly (in some time). Thanks. :)

Comment: it falls short on the propagation through macros, I think.  for example\begin{tabular}{R{1.1}R{-1.0}}
  1.0 & 2 \\
  3 & \bfseries -4 \\
\end{tabular}
it's not a big problem and elsewhere, too.  just wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 7):

And this one uses `pgfplotstable` which provides `fonts by sign={<TeX code for positive>}{<TeX code for negative>}`

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=&,row sep=\\,
    columns/one/.style={fonts by sign={\color{blue}}{\color{red}}},
    columns/two/.style={fonts by sign={\color{blue}}{\color{red}}},
]{
  one & two \\
  1.0 & 2 \\
  3 & -4 \\
 }
```

[image]

```
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to detect `-` you don't need the full parsing capabilities of the other packages, just define `-` to make things red:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,color}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$\mathcode`\-"8000\relax\color{blue}}r<$}
\makeatletter
{\catcode`\-\active
\gdef-{\color{red}\mathchar"2200\relax}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{R R}
  -1 & 2 \\
  3 & -4 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thx, david.  actually, this is almost comically simple and it will suffice in 99 out of 100 cases.  (in 1 out of 100, I may have some cells that start with \bfseries or some macro here that won't propagate through.)  for curiosity---and I presume no---can such a really simple macro be extended to use whitespace (perl regex \s+) instead of '&' and \n as \\ , too, ala pgfplotstable?

Comment: @ivoWelch I'm not sure I understand the question but I assume that the answer is yes. This isn't using `&` and `\\ ` in any essential way it just defines - to change the color then relies on tex grouping in this case the groups are proivided by table cells, but explicit `{}` groups would work and if you have a space delimited macro that is grouping cells that would work too

Answer (score 1):

red if it starts with a minus, blue if it starts with a different catcode 12 character, black otherwise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,xcolor}
\def\testnext#1#2{#1\ifx-#2\color{red}\else\ifcat#20\color{blue}\else\fi\fi#2}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\testnext}r<{}}
\begin{tabular}{R R}
one & two \\
  -1 & 2 \\
  3 & -4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I made it a little more flexible: `newcommand{\negnumformat}{\color{red}}  % -1
\newcommand{\posnumformat}{\color{blue}} % +1
\newcommand{\numformat}{\color{black}}   % 1
\newcommand{\txtformat}{\color{black}}   % A
\def\testnext#1#2{#1\ifx-#2\negnumformat$#2$\else\ifx+#2\posnumformat$#2$\else\ifcat#20\numformat$#2$\else\txtformat#2\fi\fi\fi}`